# Magento 2 - Links in Admin wont work

Tags: magento, admin, magento2

I try to install a new magento 2.

If I login in the admin all the menus and links won't work (also the logout, too).

What I do wrong - I read something about that problem and I've try to change the di.xml but that wont change anything.

at the console I see a lot of errors for example ""NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://presentim.de/pub/static/version1481817482/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/fonts/opensans/regular/opensans-400.woff""

But in the pub/statis folder is no folder "version148...."!? Maybe it can help to find the reason for the disabled menu?

Comment: Hi, did you tried to set permissions on pub directory? please try to type chmod 777 pub -R in your magento root directory. Also please check apache/nginx user/group and files user/group. It seems you don't have access to js/css files.
also you may try to clean the cache and regenerate assets

Comment: In wich folders are the "nginx" "js/css" and "user/group" do you mean?
How i can leacn cache and regenerate assets if in admin are no sublinks avivable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to try run this commands,

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```