# Magento 2 Install Windows Admin Broken Links

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I use XAMPP on Windows 10. I installed Magento 2.20 community. My admin URLs are all broken:

[image]

Is there another version I should use? I tried to run the commands from this post:

[Magento 2 - Links in Admin wont work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168461/magento-2-links-in-admin-wont-work)

[image]

In my console, I see these errors:

```
/Magento2/pub/static/version1559572638/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ytheme-magento.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
/Magento2/pub/static/version1559572638/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
require.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost/Magento2/pub/static/version1559572638/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/jstree/themes/default/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
mixins.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
requirejs-config.js:71 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at requirejs-config.js:71
    at requirejs-config.js:78
    at requirejs-config.js:416
magento-icon.svg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):38 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at (index):38
(index):87 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):87
(index):295 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):295
(index):428 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):428
(index):473 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):473
(index):514 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):514
(index):537 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):537
(index):560 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):560
admin-icons.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-400.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-600.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-700.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
admin-icons.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-700.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
admin-icons.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-600.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-400.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-700.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-600.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-400.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I mean.. it does say Windows isn't supported for M2 .. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: your best option is to create a Virtual Machine and run Magento through that (on Linux)

Comment: Try to use a VM tool like Vagrant https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers

Answer (score 0):

I run Magento 2 on Windows (for development) successfully although I use WAMP. My recipe for setting it up is as follows (I adapted it from another stackexchange Q&A but can't find it). Note my locale is en_GB, replace yours below:

1. Run grunt clean which will clean several of the folders below quickly (*)
2. *delete var/cache
3. *delete var/view_preprocessed
4. *delete pub/static/* (don't delete the .htaccess)
5. delete generated/* and not .htaccess
6. delete var/composer_home
7. run php bin/magento cache:flush
8. run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme YOUR/theme en_GB [en_GB is essential]
9. run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend en_GB [en_GB is essential]
10. delete all themes/languages you don't actually use from pub/static/frontend
11. run php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy --locale="en_GB" --theme="YOUR/theme" css/styles-m css/styles-l css/email css/email-inline
12. grunt commands below need to be run as administrator
13. Copy a valid dev\tools\grunt\configs\theme.js that contains the theme definition if you’ve done an upgrade (as it gets overwritten)
14. DO NOT run grunt exec at all
15. run grunt less:yourtheme (and probably :backend)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't know whether the following will help you out, Please check.

In your screen shot i can see that you are already in magento/bin path, so here you have to run below command

```
sudo magento setup:upgrade
```

And for second command yo are using two php in command.

- First Note : Magento2 doesn't support in windows version. But, can run.
- If you are installing magento2.2 please make sure you are using php7 or 7x, magento2.2 will not support older versions.
- Check your apache2 a2enmode is enabled or not, because it will make issues on redirection.
- Check your all files have enough permission to load, for your local you can check with giving full permission for app/etc,var/*,pub/static/*,generate/*.
- Once everything is set try to run the deployment commands with php.

You can avoid sudo if not needed. Or else go to magento root and run the earlier command which you already tried to implement.

Hope this will help you to sort out.